# Compute variations between data then transpose results using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following data in a MongoDB collection named "price":

```
[
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 1.0},
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 2.0}, // price variation => +1
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 3.0}, // price variation => +1
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 5.0}, // price variation => +2
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 8.0}, // price variation => +3
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-06T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 13.0}, // price variation => +5        
    {"date": ISODate("2017-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"), "price": 21.0}, // price variation => +8
    ...  
]
```

For each group of n elements (for example below, n = 3), I would like to aggregate this data to obtain a transposed list of variations between each price:

```
[
  {variations: [1, 1, 2]},
  {variations: [1, 2, 3]},
  {variations: [2, 3, 5]},
  {variations: [3, 5, 8]},
  ...
]
```

Is there a way to do this using the MongoDB aggregation?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a way with the aggregation framework. The problem is that you would need to know what the "previous documents" were in your style of comparison, and there is no way to do that. What you are looking for would require iterating all documents through a cursor and keeping the values in code for comparison and output.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to compute variations with an external program (Python or Node.JS)